# Display data without IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can currently fetch and display all data in the view with:

```
@model IEnumerable<Logara.Models.LogaraDB>

@foreach (var item in Model)
     {
       <tr>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeIn)
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeOut)
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
         </td>
       </tr>
     }
```

How can I fetch and display data using just `@model Logara.Models.LogaraDB` ? Can I still use foreach? Is there an easier way without HTML Helpers/Razor?

This is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Logara.Models
{
    public class LogaraDB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogaraBDContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LogaraDB> Logara { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to display the details for a single `LogaraDB` (in which case your view needs to be `@model Logara.Models.LogaraDB` and remove the loop. - it will just be `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TimeIn)` etc

Comment: You need to create a nesting level within your object that contains a collection of your LogaraDB objects.

Comment: It is really unclear what you're trying to do. Please explain your _goal_, instead of _"I want to use foreach() without an IEnumerable"_, as the latter is not possible.

Comment: I want to list _all_ of data from database (instances of object?). Is this possible without IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one single LogaraDB object just remove foreach. 
If you want to show collection but get rid of @model IEnumerable you have to add model

```
public class LogaraDBList
    {
        IEnumerable<LogaraDB> logaraDBItems {get; set;}
    }
```

and then your view would look like this:

```
@model Logara.Models.LogaraDBList

@foreach (var item in Model.logaraDBItems)
     {
       <tr>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeIn)
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeOut)
         </td>
         <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
         </td>
       </tr>
     }
```